# How to get different dimension resized Images(more than 1) from a Single Image during publishing if using DD4T 2.0 TBBs already in the CT

Tags: dd4t, multimedia, image

We do not want to resize the original Large image at application level by using the DD4T 2.0 Java classes because of performance issue; since the page contain lots of images we can not do this resize operation at render of page.

Image Resizer TBB is of no help if using DD4T TBB I believe.

Comment: Do you want to do this while publishing or not? It's possible either way, but your title says one thing, and your question the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest 2 options:

1. Use imaging s\w to resize dynamically based on device (assuming that's why you want to resize the images). We are moving towards similar approach where images will be served from Akamai and dynamically resized based on device using a resizing s\w. There are many tools available in the market to do it.
2. Cache assets (images) on the edge using tools like Akamai and then you can use dd4t to resize for the first request and then they are stored on Akamai until there is a change in the image and served from there. You will not need to resize on each request.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, for one single image you want to create copy of that image with different sizes. Is that correct?

There are two approaches to perform this:

1. Use TBB to resize the images and include those in package.
2. Use event system which will create resized copies of images based on the criteria you decide on save of the component. Then you will have to write it in TBB to include those different sized images.

Since you have performance concern with 1st approach, you can choose for 2nd option. Please note, if you are using event system then it will be performance hit on CME.

So either way you will have performance impact either on CME or on Publishing. You have to choose which one fits your requirement and helps you long term.

Comment: >> "if you are using event system then it will be performance hit on CME." This type of operation is a perfect candidate for an Async event, done post save, which will _not_ impact CME.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution as well for the better performance  -

1. Create a Embedded Schema, where you can add 3 different different version(According to size) of 1 image.
2. Link this embedded schema to your main schema and maintain the different version of same image from CMS side.
3. Implement the logic[1] at the time page render and pick the right multimedia from broker.

[1] depending on device or bandwidth.